# "yum clean" hangs - what to try next?

Tags: linux, yum, strace

I run a number of CentOS servers. I was recently doing the occasional `yum update` but this failed on a handful of the servers. On most I have been able to move forward by doing:

```
# yum clean all
# rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
# rpm --rebuilddb
# yum update
```

However on one server, the `yum clean` command hangs. I have tried running:

```
# yum -v --noplugins clean all
```

but I get no output at all. Yum just hangs, and will sit there for hours if I let it, not using any cpu, just stopped. Doing

```
# strace -f yum -v --noplugins clean all
```

produces quite a lot of output, but then stops with:

```
...
stat64("/var/lib/rpm/__db.003", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=450560, ...}) = 0
open("/var/lib/rpm/__db.003", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
mmap2(NULL, 450560, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 4, 0) = 0xb6b34000
close(4)                                = 0
stat64("/var/lib/rpm/Packages", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14938112, ...}) = 0
open("/var/lib/rpm/Packages", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
read(4, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0a\25\6\0\10\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\10\0\0k\t\0\0"..., 512) = 5
12
close(4)                                = 0
open("/var/lib/rpm/Packages", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14938112, ...}) = 0
futex(0xb6b7bd1c, FUTEX_WAIT, 1, NULL
```

At this point I'm feeling stuck. This is a production server, so I don't want to just blow it away, or even blow away all the yum information. Apart from the yum stuff, the server is working fine.

Comment: do you have any nfs mounted filesystems that are currently hung?

Comment: What does `lsof` reveal, if anything?

Comment: There is a single root fs (with plenty of space) and then just proc, sysfs and tmpfs (and tmpfs has plenty of space).

Comment: @JannePikkarainen - `lsof /var/lib/rpm/Packages` originally showed an old rpm process. I've killed that, and my yum, checked that `lsof` didn't show anything else accessing the file, and tried again, but I stop at the same place. I've also scanned through the full `lsof` output and not seen anything that looks likely.

Comment: Also, I can open the file `/var/lib/rpm/Packages` for reading in another application.

Comment: Does the server have access to outside world? Yes, I know, yum is not supposed to contact the net that soon, but ...

Comment: @JannePikkarainen - yes there is network access. I can ssh into and out of it, and ping other servers. I can load web pages in lynx.

Comment: need output: rpm -qa|grep yum

Comment: Try doing the `yum clean all` along with `yum update` after rebuilding the databases (`rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*` and `rpm --rebuilddb`) instead of before.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, all my yum commands were hanging.

I ran the following commands

```
rm /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rm /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock
rm /var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock
```

So a combination of some of the above comments and answers.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked like a charm for me! I saw the other superuser thread regarding a similar issue, but it turns out the locks were what were freezing it for me. Appreciate this greatly! https://superuser.com/questions/384963/yum-hangs-and-wont-respond

Comment: second command helped me in centos

Answer (score 4):

On my Redhat 7.2 this helps to let run the yum commands.

```
 rm /var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock
```

Comment: This corrupted my `yum` installation, but then running `sudo rpm --rebuilddb && yum clean all` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, but if none of the commands from the other answers helped then I'd check the command `package-cleanup`.

All the proposed commands are for handling the RPM database, but it could be that there's something broken in the relation of some installed packages.

From `man package-cleanup`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       package-cleanup is a program for cleaning up the locally-installed RPMs.
EXAMPLES
       List all dependency problems:
              package-cleanup --problems

       List all packages that are not in any Yum repository:
              package-cleanup --orphans
```

I'd start with the command in the second example, I've used it before and it solved some weird issues I had in one of my CentOS machines which was related to `yum clean`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had all but one server with

```
[main]
enabled=1
```

in

```
/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf
```

Setting this to `enabled=0` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above but also:

```
ps -ef | grep yum # kill off all yum processes
ps -ef | grep rpm # kill off rpm processes
```

I couldn't get any of the above to work until I did this.

Credit to: https://cloudlinux.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004580385-If-RPM-or-yum-processes-hangs